# How to run python in a makefile and change the output name or directory?

Tags: python, file-io, makefile, rename

I have a long list of files to process, in 10 steps of python programing, I was trying to create a `makefile` to run all those files. For some reason, I don't know why, when I run them as the code below, the output was empty after the second step. When I run them, calling one by one, the code works, but I change the name of the output in each step, or change the output from folder, I don't know how to make it in `makefiles`. I accept other suggestions apart from `makefiles` too (like `pypelines` ... I am a bit lost with shell commands)

My `makefile` looks like this

```
zero::
        for f in `ls data/wikiMaths/*.html`; do \
        python src/maths/stripHtmlMaths.py $$f > $$f; \
        done

one::   
        for f in `ls data/wikiMaths/*.html`; do \
        python src/maths/Wiki2Text.py $$f > $$f; \
        done

three:: 
        for f in `ls data/wikiMaths/*.txt`; do \
        python src/maths/striphtml.py $$f > $$f; \
        done

four::
        for f in `ls data/wikiMaths/*.txt`; do \
        python src/maths/sipTrash.py $$f > $$f; \
        done

five::
        for f in `ls data/wikiMaths/*.txt`; do \
        python src/maths/tagFormula.py $$f > $$f; \
        done

six::
        for f in `ls data/wikiMaths/*.txt`; do \
        python src/maths/CountForm.py $$f > $$f; \
        done

seven::
        for f in `ls data/wikiMaths/*.txt`; do \
        python src/maths/stripWhiteSpace.py $$f > $$f; \
        done

eight::
        for f in `ls data/wikiMaths/*.txt`; do \
        python src/maths/Text2Xml.py $$f > $$f.xml; \
        done

nine::
        for f in `ls data/wikiMaths/*.xml`; do \
        python src/maths/Separate.py $$f > $$f; \
        done
```

what I wish to do is something like:

```
zero::
        for f in `ls data/wikiMaths/*.html`; do \
        python src/maths/stripHtmlMaths.py $$f > data/newFolder/$$f; \
        done

one::   
        for f in `ls data/newFolder/*.html`; do \
        python src/maths/Wiki2Text.py $$f > data/newFolderTwo/$$f.txt; \
        done
```

to replace that:

```
python src/maths/stripHtmlMaths.py data/wikiMaths/file1.html > data/newFolder/file1.html
python src/maths/Wiki2Text.py data/newFolder/file1.html > data/newFolderTwo/file1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why don't you use the power of Makefile at all; and why not concatenate all 9 actions for each file into just 1 recipe? Or why not replace this all with a simple python script. Furthermore your pipeline must be truncating the source files all the time.

Something like

```
SOURCE_FILES := $(wildcard data/wikiMaths/*.txt)
TARGET_FILES := $(SOURCE_FILES:data/wikiMaths/%.txt=output/%.txt)

all: TARGET_FILES

$(TARGET_FILES): output/%: data/wikiMaths/%
        python src/process_from_source $< > $@
```

Comment: How could I concatenate the 9 of them?... depending on the action I access the file in lines and others as one text, so changing the script I can read as text a file stored as list in the previews step

Answer (score 0):

Scripting in Python is more flexible than makefiles
You can do comething like

```
import os
scriptFiles = ('script1.py', 'script2.py')
for scriptFile in scriptFiles:
    for _, _, files in os.walk(path): 
        for filename in files:
            exeLine = 'c:\\python27\\python.exe ' + scriptFile + ' ' + filename + ' > ' + filename + 'out'; os.system(exeLine)
        break # run os.walk(path) only once
```

You'd need to change the filenames, but I hope thi idea is clear